# Organic natural sustainable alternatives to commercial Hair Styling products; clay, wax, pomade, mousse, gel?

Tags: alternatives, biodegradable-waste, organic, personal-hygiene

I am looking for organic natural materials & receipes for Hair clay, wax, pomade, mousse, gel for hair styling, not shampoo. If there are some examples please point me to them.

- Any that can be easily DIY home made with organic/ plant based ingredients?
- Also open to finding available products that are made in a more sustainable, organic fashion without/ lesser use of chemicals; especially toxic ones. What kind of stuff do they use?
- Even better, if some of this is bio sourced and bio degradable.

Comment: The hair wax I use lists as its main ingredients "Aqua, Ceresin, Alcohol Denat., Petrolatum, Carnauba" - i.e. water, alcohol, various waxes and mineral oil.  Water, beeswax and vegetable oil are the key ingredients in "cold cream" (google it) - a traditional moisturiser that can be made at home.  I have sometimes wondered if these recipes could be tweaked by increasing the amount of beeswax and reducing the water and oil (possibly also including alcohol e.g. in the form of vodka) to give something like an organic hair wax.  May be worth experimenting?

Comment: Philosophical question; is it "organic" to do anything with your hair other than just let it grow?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of alternatives to make your own shampoo at home and many of them use [castile soap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castile_soap) (because it doesn't involve any kind of animal fat in the production process). You have a few examples [here](http://mypurepursuit.blogspot.de/p/shampoo-recipes_19.html) and [here](http://nourishingjoy.com/homemade-shampoo/).

The idea behind all of them is pretty similar, mixing castile soap (I am pretty sure that other kinds of soap can be used but this is the one I have tried and I'm familiar with) with distilled water to get a nice texture and with herbs and essential oils for aroma and other properties (chamomile extract is used in many industrial shampoos).

If you don't want to mess around and make your own shampoo there are also a lot of companies that make natural grooming products of all kinds (you can even often find some natural cosmetic projects in Kickstarter [1](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/jasmineofjaza/jaza-natural-cruelty-free-cosmetics?ref=nav_search), [2](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1979747841/double-dyed-cosmetics-cruelty-free-brand?ref=nav_search)). This products are made with natural materials without lots of chemicals, so I would also recommend you look around for "natural products" and read carefully the ingredients of the products you are interested in to see if they fit or not your needs.

Comment: I am looking for organic natural materials & receipes for Gel, Pomade, Mousse for hair styling, not shampoo. If there are some examples please point me to them.

Answer (score 1):

Over the last 18 months I've stopped using shampoo at all (just water, and occasionally cider vinegar to prevent smells!) - Google for "no poo hair" for all the lowdown.

As well as eliminating shampoo (and the associated plastic bottles) I no longer use hair wax.  I used to use this daily for styling my hair but now I don't need it: the natural oils and waxes in my hair do a better job.  I think my hair looks better, it takes less time to wash and style, I save money, and I produce less waste.

It will depend on your hairstyle though: you may not manage a mohican like this...

Comment: Can you enrich and update the answer with what hair type, hairstyles & length (through the comparative timeline), etc you have/ had. Since we dont have pictures its rather vague to imagine how, who it works for - male vs female, hair variety, length, styling, bangs, side, middle etc.